# How to add next and previous buttons for this custom scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

i have this http://jsfiddle.net/utLytLmt/ with a custom scroll with differents points to make scroll to, i'm using the [jQuery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) plugin but there is not an option to make navigation buttons (the complementary jQuery.serialScroll seems to be made only for when the distance between points is equal).

is there a way to make these next and previous buttons to move betweeen the sections?

```
<button id="next">Next</button> | <button id="prev">Previous</button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [modified your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6rb17n0/2/) to get it working.

I started by changing your code above to this:

```
var scrollPoint = [70, 130, 210, 360, 445, 580, 7130, 816, 933, 1000];
var scrollDuration = 2500;

$("input[type=button]").each(function (index) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $("body").scrollTo(scrollPoint[index] +  "px", scrollDuration);
    });
});
```

*(rather than using the button index as here, it would be better to use hrefs or data attributes as indexes to your scrollPositions though)*

This allows you to figure out the previous or next point based on on

```
var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
//sometimes scroll position is 69.9995... We want it to be 70:
scrollPosition = Math.round(scrollPosition);
```

**[Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/y6rb17n0/2/)** *(I've assumed the "7130px" scroll point is a mistake)*

Here is the same thing with a reduced `reduce` function (which finds the next/previous point): http://jsfiddle.net/y6rb17n0/3/

**Important Note**

A body with a height of 1000px can scroll to `1000 - $(window).height()` (so your body needs to be larger for this group of `scrollPoints`).

Comment: Thanks mate, i like the other answer too but your code allows me to add the scroll points directly in the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `data` attributes for the offset and do this:

Check the [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/utLytLmt/4/)

**EXPLANATION**

Every time you click on an input or prev/next button, store the target offset to a hidden input.

Then, on the next prev/next button click, check for the stored value, find the input that has a `data-top` equal to the stored value and find the previous or next element and trigger the scroll with the new element's `data-top` value.

**UPDATED THE DEMO**

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me1" class="next1" data-top="70">
....
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:not(#stored)', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var t = that.attr('data-top');
    $('#stored').val(t);
    $("body").scrollTo(t + 'px', 2500);
});

$(document).on('click', '#btnHolder > button', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var id = that.attr('id');
    var stVal = $('#stored').val();
    //console.log(stVal);
    if (stVal) {
        if (id == 'next') {
            var tp = $('[data-top="' + stVal + '"]').next().attr('data-top');        
        } else if (id == 'prev') {
            var tp = $('[data-top="' + stVal + '"]').prev().attr('data-top');        
        }
        console.log($('[data-top="' + stVal + '"]').next().attr('data-top'));
        $("body").scrollTo(tp + 'px', 2500);
        $('#stored').val(tp);
    }
});
```